# How to turn off AltGr+p shortcut in aptana?

Tags: aptana

When I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in Aptana, a message in yellow box will be shown: Tooltip will automatically hide in 10 seconds. Click to focus. Type escape to dismiss when focused. I want to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> for other purpose. How can I turn off <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in Aptana? It is not possible in Window > preferences > keys.

Comment: This is not a relevant question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command executed is:

**Commands -> Bundle Development -> Show Scope and Matching Theme Rule**

corresponding to :

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

I would suggest to follow instructions for **Modifying the Built-In Bundles**:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys

and change the binding for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> that apparently is also bound to <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>